# Python dataframe group and create columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV file it has 5 million lines, it is like this

```
id, name, house 
1,a,house1,
1,aa,house2
1,aaa,house3
2,b,house4
2,bb,house5
2,bbb, house6
3,c, house7
3,cc, house8
3,ccc, house9
4,d, house10
4,dd, house11
4,ddd, house12
4,dddd, house13
```

I want to group them by id and for result, I need to create this

```
1,a,house1,aa,house2,aaa,houes3
2,b,house4,bb,house5,bbb,houes6
3,c,house7,cc,house8,ccc,houes9
4,d,house10,dd,house11,ddd,house12
```

also as you can see that I just try to get first 3,I have a little script which can do what I want, its too slow and not clean, so how can I do better,

```
    import pandas as pd
    import progressbar

    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    print(df.columns)
    df = df.reset_index()
    l = []
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(df.index) +1,
                                  widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()])
    print(len(df.index))
    bar.start()

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        tmp_sub_list = [row['id']]
        bar.update(i+1)
        for _, row2 in df.iterrows():
            if row['id'] == row2['id']:
                tmp_sub_list.append(row2['name'])
                tmp_sub_list.append(row2['house'])
            if len(tmp_sub_list) >= 7:
                break
        l.append(tmp_sub_list)

    df_result = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=[
        'id', 'name_first', 'house_first', 'name_second', 'house_second', 'name_threeth', 'house_threeth'])
    bar.finish()
```

also, I am trying to use the progress bar,

Comment: Please always include the [tag:pandas] question when asking about pandas, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki. Python itself doesn't have dataframes at all.

Comment: What about house13 for 4... it is not in your output.

Comment: I just need to get  first three-row which have same id, so I don't need this row `4,dddd, house13`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dataframe is already sorted.

You can use `groupby` and `head` to take top 3 rows and aggregate into string list with `join`.

In the sample data, you have spaces for house columns so I added `strip` but this is the artifact of copy and paste, take out the `strip` part.

Also, there are spaces for columns, and if your original csv has space for columns, rename the column to no-space string before next code.

```py
df = df.groupby('id').head(3).groupby('id').agg({
         'name': lambda x: ','.join(x),
         'house': lambda x: ','.join([y.strip() for y in x])
     })
```

This makes the dataframe to

```
        name                    house
id
1   a,aa,aaa     house1,house2,house3
2   b,bb,bbb     house4,house5,house6
3   c,cc,ccc     house7,house8,house9
4   d,dd,ddd  house10,house11,house12
```

You can use `str.split` to turns these to columns.

```py
df[['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']] = df.name.str.split(',', expand=True)
df[['house_first', 'house_second', 'house_third']] = df.house.str.split(',', expand=True)

df = df.reset_index().drop(['name', 'house'], axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have a question how can I use progress bar

Comment: how big is your data?

Comment: You can wrap start/end to top/bottom of these lines and increment between each code. However, each line has different computation, so it doesn't quite much with the progress percentage. 

And if your data is smaller than 100ks, this runs within a second and progress bar doesn't really mean much.

Comment: its more than 5 million

Comment: did progress bar work?  the way I mentioned in last comment?